# Conditionally evaluated debug statements in Python

Tags: python, debugging, logging

Python has a few ways of printing "trace" output. `print`, `import logging`, `stdout.write` can be used to print debugging info, but they all have one drawback: even if the logger's threshold is too high or the stream is closed, Python will still evaluate the arguments to the print statement. (*Strict Evaluation*) This could cost a string format or more.

The obvious fix is to put the string-creating code into a lambda, and use our own logging function to call the lambda conditionally (this one checks the `__debug__` builtin variable, which is set to False whenever python is started with `-O` for optimizations) :

```
def debug(f):
  if __debug__:
    print f()
    #stdout.write(f())
    #logging.debug(f())

for currentItem in allItems:
  debug(lambda:"Working on {0}".format(currentItem))
```

The advantage is not calling `str(currentItem)` and `string.format` in release builds, and the disadvantage is having to type in `lambda:` on every logging statement.

Python's `assert` statement is treated specially by the Python compiler. If python is run with `-O`, then any assert statements are discarded without any evaluation. You can exploit this to make another conditionally-evaluated logging statement:

```
assert(logging.debug("Working on {0}".format(currentItem)) or True)
```

This line will not be evaluated when Python is started with `-O`.

The short-circuit operators 'and' and 'or' can even be used:

```
__debug__ and logging.debug("Working on {0}".format(currentItem));
```

But now we're up to 28 characters plus the code for the output string.

The question I'm getting to: Are there any standard python statements or functions that have the same conditional-evaluation properties as the `assert` statement? Or, does anyone have any alternatives to the methods presented here?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but it looks like the `logging` module already has this problem solved when it comes to string formatting. I was looking for a more general case that I could use when the body of the print statement isn't just `%` or `string.format`; for example, `", ".join([x.foo for x in exes if x in whys])`

Comment: +1 for the "short-circuit" idea!
Yep, _standard_ string formatting is solved, but sometimes you have costly custom code to run in order to produce debug output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder how much a call to `logging.debug` impacts the performance when there are no handlers.

However the `if __debug__:` statement is evaluated only once, even in the body of a function

```
$ python -O
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 26 2010, 22:31:48)
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dis
>>> import logging
>>> def debug(*a, **kw):
...  if __debug__:
...   logging.debug(*a, **kw)
... 
>>> dis.dis(debug)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE        
>>>
```

and the logger can format the message for you using the string formatting operator. Here a slightly modified example taken from the [logging.debug documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug)

```
FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s %(clientip)s %(user)-8s %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
d = { 'clientip' : '192.168.0.1', 'user' : 'fbloggs' }
debug('Protocol problem: %s', 'connection reset', extra=d)
```

In this case the message string is never evaluated if the optimizations are turned off.

Answer (score 4):

if all your debug function will take is a string, why not change it to take a format string and the arguments:

```
debug(lambda:"Working on {0}".format(currentItem))
```

becomes

```
debug("Working on {0}", currentItem)
```

and

```
if __debug__:
    def debug(format, *values):
        print format.format(*values)
else:
    def debug(format, *values): pass
```

this has all the advantages of your first option without the need for a lambda and if the `if __debug__:` is moved out the of function so that it is only tested once when the containing module is loaded the overhead of the statement is just one function call.

Comment: Hmm... this is part of what the logger module does for me. `logging.debug` takes a msg and args, which it later passes to the `%` operator in `LogRecord.getMessage()` which is only called when needed. The logging module even gives me a way to override the factory for LogRecords, so I can drop in a subclass that uses string.format instead of `%`. This isn't a general enough solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

any standard python statements or function with the same conditional behavior as assert -> no, as far as I know.

Note that no string interpolation is performed by `logging` functions if the threshold is too high (but you still pay for the method call and some of the checks inside).

You can expand on Dan D.'s suggestion by monkeypatching logging.logger when you code starts:

```
import logging
if __debug__:
    for methname in ('debug', 'info', 'warning', 'error', 'exception'):
         logging.logger.setattr(methname, lambda self, *a, **kwa: None)
```

and then use logging as usual. You can even change the initial test to allow the replacement of the logging methods even in non optimized mode

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [eval](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) method:

```
import inspect

def debug(source):
  if __debug__:
    callers_locals = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals
    print eval(source, globals(),  callers_locals)

for currentItem in ('a', 'b'):
  debug('"Working on {0}".format(currentItem)')
```