# Are C++ style logging macros possible in Python?

Tags: python, c++, logging, macros

Is it possible to implement the equivalent of the following (pseudo-)code in Python?

```
#define DEBUG(topic, msg) LOG_IMPL(Logger.DEBUG, topic, msg)
#define INFO(topic, msg) LOG_IMPL(Logger.INFO, topic, msg)
#define LOG_IMPL(level, topic, msg) if(Logger.level() <= level) { Logger.log(level, topic, msg); }

DEBUG("MyComponent", "What you logging at?")
```

The benefit here being you don't have to evaluate the string log messages, e.g. joining strings, calling .format(), etc.)

**UPDATE**:

[Lazy logger message string evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148790/lazy-logger-message-string-evaluation) - this answers my question so I will vote to close this post.

Comment: Wow, that's disgusting C++ macro with no purpose.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Those defines could easily be implemented in any language as functions.

Comment: @Graeme: As I understand it, you are not only asking for a nice logging module (and the python built-in is great) but also for a system that does not evaluate the log messages (if constructing them is computationally expensive) if logging is disabled. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @AlexWilson: You are correct, it's the cost of expensive log messages I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @DeadMG: I've wrapped up the logger in my own class so I can amoung other things add some additional levels (e.g. TRACE). By calling my functions I don't benefit from the lazy evaluation of the underlying logging library (which I am using).

Comment: @Graeme: I take it I can't tempt you with my lambda suggestion then? It does offer a fully general way of preventing any compute involved in the log message being evaluated when not required...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lazy logger message string evaluation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148790/lazy-logger-message-string-evaluation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution allowing lazy evaluation of log message whilst still allowing me to encapsulate custom formatters and handlers inside a small logging proxy class.

The format string will not be evalulated unless the log message is written (logging handles this); this achieved by passing the format string and arguments seperately.

```
@classmethod 
def info(cls, component, msg, *args):     
    """Log an info message"""     
    cls.__log(cls.Level.INFO, component, msg, (args)  

@classmethod 
def __log(cls, level, component, msg, *args):    
    """Log a message at the requested level"""     
    logging.getLogger("local").log(level, " - ".join([component, msg.format(*args)])) 

Logger.info("MyComponent", "My message with arg '{0}'", "TestArg")
```

Answer (score 9):

Python comes with batteries included, and a [`logging module`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) is part of the stdlib:

```
from logging import getLogger

log = getLogger('my.module')

log.debug('Debug level messages')
log.warning('Warning!')
log.info('Informative message')
log.error('Error messages')
log.exception('Use this in an exception handler, the exception will be included automatically')
```

The above set of methods are shortcuts for the `log.log(level, msg)` method, which takes arbitrary (integer) levels, and the `logging` module defines `DEBUG`, `WARNING` and other levels.

The methods support lazy evaluation of [python string formatting templates](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations); extra arguments are interpolated *only* when the log level of the message actually exceeds the logging level being recorded:

```
log.warning('Warning message: the %s is missing %i frobnars', systemname, count)
```

The above message will be logged with the equivalent of `'Warning message: the %s is missing %i frobnars' % (systemname, count)` only if the log message actually reaches a handler.

Comment: This makes sense but I've wrapped up the logger in my own class so I can amoung other things add some additional levels (e.g. TRACE). By calling my functions I don't benefit fomr the lazy evaluation of the underlying logging library (which I am using).

Comment: @Graeme: When in Rome, do as the romans do. You can customize the native `logging` module to do almost anything you want. Perhaps you can use your custom class as a `Handler` which will be called by `logging` ?

Comment: @Graeme: levels are numeric; just call `log.log(yourlevel, msg)`. `logging.DEBUG` is 10, so `TRACE = 5` would be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @ereOn: I have written a very light wrapper which calls into logging to format the log as I wish, add my custom levels, etc.  It's a simple singleton which all my apps use and which has the 7 or so functions I require for logging - I'm not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Graeme: I think you are. The logging module provides handlers and formatters, where you can format messages any way you like without subclassing the logger and loosing functionality.

Comment: @Graeme: It always difficult to somehow "ditch" (or "not use") code you have put of efforts in because you discover too late something existed that fitted the purpose. You would probably gain a lot of maintainability by making your logging functions interface with the `logging` module.

Comment: @Martin: I want a Logger class I can use without having to manually add for matters and handlers to it in each of my projects. I wrap up this bit of work in the constructor (encapsulation) and use a simple proxy interface. I'm not subclassing either.

Comment: @Graeme: Well it's your call anyway. But I fail to see why you can't just put this particular initialization code in some common function and just call that function in projects that needs it.

Answer (score 2):

How about using lambdas for the messages:

```
log( lambda : (string1 + string2 + "%d %d" % (val1, val2)) )
```

And have the log function only call the function passed in if logging is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `logging` module?
Example:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
```

Source: http://docs.python.org/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial