# Python using wrong version of pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

I have a Python project which the `requirements.txt` states pymongo 3.5.1

but when I run my script I am getting an error because it is trying to use pymongo 2.8.

I have run `pip install -U pymongo`, `pip3 install -U pymongo`, `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` but these all say that I already have pymongo 3.5.1 so I am not sure where it is pulling it from.

I am using a virtualenv which has pymongo 3.5.1 installed too so I am not sure where it is calling v2.8 from.

I am running my script in the virtualenv too, just to make sure it's pulling the correct versions through.

The stack trace is:

```
'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'delete_many' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/luke/projects/vuln_backend/core/maintenance.py", line 30, in db_clear
    result = db.vulnerabilities.delete_many({})
  File "/home/luke/envs/vuln_backend/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1773, in __call__
    self.__name.split(".")[-1])
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'delete_many' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

The code that is trying to call this is:

```
def db_clear(mongo_server,mongo_port):
    try:
        logging.info(pymongo.version)
        logging.info('Connecting to MongoDB')
        client = MongoClient(mongo_server, mongo_port)
        db = client['vuln_sets']
        logging.info('Connected to MongoDB')
        result = db.vulnerabilities.delete_many({})
        logging.info('Delete Successful!')
        logging.info('Deleted ' + result.deleted_count + ' vulnerabilities')
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)
```

Comment: What you see in `pip list`  output?

Comment: pymongo (3.5.1)
pymongo-amplidata (2.8.post2)

Comment: please provide error stacktrace

Comment: and the code that causes the error

Comment: I updated the question to include these bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pymongo-amplidata` overwrites pymongo to old version after installing
you can fix it this way:

```
pip uninstall pymongo-amplidata -y
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pymongo
```

after that you got more expected error :) and maybe you'll find interesting to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11955787/4249707) question and answers to it before fixing this bug

```
24/11/2017 15:45:50 [root] [INFO] 3.5.1
24/11/2017 15:45:50 [root] [INFO] Connecting to MongoDB
24/11/2017 15:45:50 [root] [INFO] Connected to MongoDB
24/11/2017 15:45:50 [root] [INFO] Delete Successful!
24/11/2017 15:45:50 [root] [ERROR] must be str, not int
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/elruso/projects/3.6 test/47460535.py", line 17, in db_clear
    logging.info('Deleted ' + result.deleted_count + ' vulnerabilities')
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Comment: I fixed the logging issue by wrapping the `result.deleted_count` in a `str()` as follows: `logging.info('Deleted ' + str(result.deleted_count) + ' vulnerabilities')`

Comment: on my opinion  `logging.info('Deleted %s vulnerabilities',  result.deleted_count)` more pythonic way to do it