# Usage of passing args to python logging function

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I was wondering if there's an actual usage of the `args` option that is passed into a `logging` call that cannot be done with string-formatting. For example:

```
logging.info('hello, %s' % 'Bob')
```

vs.

```
logging.info('hello, %s', 'Bob')
```

Are these two variations to do the same thing? Or is there actually some use with passing in args to the logging call that you cannot do with string formatting?

Comment: The result is the same but the second variant is more performant. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955787/idiomatic-python-logging-format-string-args-list-vs-inline-string-formatting) for a detailed discussion.