# Lazy Evaluation of Django QuerySet in log message

Tags: python, django

If I have my log level set to INFO, both of the following lines will cause the queryset to still be evaluated, even though the data is not printed:

```
logger.debug("Count is %s"%Widget.objects.count())
logger.debug("Count is %s", Widget.objects.count())
```

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: `count()` return int, not queryset. (evaluated immediately). See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

Comment: but even if I use a queryset I have the same problem, e.g. logger.debug('count is %s', User.objects.all()) runs the query immediately, even if the log level is set to INFO so that the message won't appear in logs

Comment: Becasue even though message is not displayed, it is converted to string; that required evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4149190/390973

```
class Lazy(object):
    def __init__(self,func):
        self.func=func
    def __str__(self):
        return self.func()

logger.debug(Lazy(lambda: "Count is %s"%Widget.objects.count()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Only way would be to store value in variable

```
obj_count = Widget.objects.count()
logger.debug("Count is %d"% obj_count)
logger.debug("Count is %d", obj_count)
```

Comment: But the issue is that I don't want the query to be run if the log level is INFO, because the message will not be displayed