# Python: how to do lazy debug logging

Tags: python, logging, lazy-evaluation, python-logging

I have some python like this:

```
def foo():
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    # do something here
    logger.debug('blah blah {}'.format(expensive_func()))

foo()
```

where `expensive_func()` is a function that returns string and that it is expensive to execute.

When developping, the log level is set to DEBUG, and `expensive_func()` get executed, the message get logged, everything is fine.

The problem is that when I set the log level strictly greater than DEBUG, say WARNING, in production env, obviously the return value of `expensive_func()` won't get logged, but the expensive function itself will still be executed.

My question is: how to prevent python from excutting the expensive function when the logging level is WARNING?

I don't want to delete that debug line or add something like `if level > DEBUG: return` in the expensive function.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I visited [Lazy logger message string evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148790/lazy-logger-message-string-evaluation?rq=1) just now, but not satisfied with it, mainly because:

1. It's some what ugly;
2. Even if I wrap the expensive function with some Lazy class, what shoud I do when I have two expensive functions? (shown below).

```
class Lazy:
    def __init__(self, func, *a, **ka):
        self.func= func
        self.a = a
        self.ka= ka
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.func(*self.a, **self.ka))

# Though this is ugly, it works
logger.debug('Message: %s', Lazy(expensive_func))

# What if I wanted to do this?
# logger.debug('Message: {}'.format(expf_1(expf_2(some_arg))))
# Maybe I can modify class Lazy to make something like this to work
# but it really doesn't feel right
# logger.debug('Message: {}', Lazy(expf_1, Lazy(expf_2, some_arg)))
```

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lazy logger message string evaluation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148790/lazy-logger-message-string-evaluation)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at [this part](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.isEnabledFor) of the documentation.

**Update:** Logging already supports lazy evaluation, but slightly differently to the way described in your comnment. For example, see the following script:

```
import logging

def expensive_func(*args):
    print('Expensive func called: %s' % (args,))
    return sum(args)

class DeferredMessage(object):
    def __init__(self, func, *args):
        self.func = func
        self.args = args

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Message {0}'.format(self.func(*self.args))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig()
    logging.info(DeferredMessage(expensive_func, 1, 2))
    logging.warning(DeferredMessage(expensive_func, 3, 4))
    logging.error(DeferredMessage(expensive_func, 5, 6))
```

When the above script is run, it should print

```
Expensive func called: (3, 4)
WARNING:root:Message 7
Expensive func called: (5, 6)
ERROR:root:Message 11
```

which shows that a potentially expensive function is only called when necessary. The example above can, of course, be generalised to allow the format string to be passed to the `DeferredMessage`, and to use `kwargs`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks, I adopted this method. I can see that you are a maintainer of the logging package, is there any chance that this module will support some feature like this (lazy evaluation)? Maybe in a style like `logger.debug('Message {}', F)`, where `F` is a tuple like `(expensive_func, [arg1, arg2])`. If the current log level is suitable, the `expensive_func` will get called by the logging module and then produces some string used to fill the blank.

Answer (score 8):

As Vinay Sajip suggests, you can do the following:

```
def foo():
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    if logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):
        logger.debug('blah blah {}'.format(expensive_func()))
        logger.debug('Message: {}'.format(expf_1(expf_2(some_arg))))
        logger.debug('Message: {}', Lazy(expf_1, Lazy(expf_2, some_arg)))
foo()
```

**Which is already lazy!**

That's because the then-expressions

```
        logger.debug('blah blah {}'.format(expensive_func()))
        logger.debug('Message: {}'.format(expf_1(expf_2(some_arg))))
        logger.debug('Message: {}', Lazy(expf_1, Lazy(expf_2, some_arg)))
```

are only evaluated if and only if `logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG)` returns `True`, i.e. if and only if their **evaluation is needed**.

---

Even more

```
logging.info(DeferredMessage(expensive_func, 1, 2))
```

**is not as lazy as one may think**: `DeferredMessage(expensive_func, 1, 2)` have to be evaluated in an *eager* fashion. Which is in addition slower than evaluating:

```
    if logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):
```

Comment: See also my [Lazy logger message string evaluation answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22205835/3070727) for benchmark results against the lazy class approach.

Comment: Hinging on a conditional statement for lazy logging bloats one's codebase a lot, it is hardly an elegant solution for an entire codebase.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stringlike` library to add laziness to your messages

E.g.:

```
logger.debug(
    'blah blah {value}'
    .format(
        value=LazyString(expensive_func)
    )
)
```

Lib link: https://github.com/CovenantEyes/py_stringlike

Answer (score 0):

An iteration on [Vinay Sajip's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21399488/1665831), to delegate lazy function call to the standard [partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) python function and also put the actual formatting in the expensive function (on_str is only wrapping):

```python
from functools import partial

def expensive_format(*args):
    print('Expensive format called: %s' % (args,))
    return 'Message {0}'.format(sum(args))

class on_str(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __str__(self):
        return self.func()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig()
    logging.info(on_str(partial(expensive_format, 1, 2)))
    logging.warning(on_str(partial(expensive_format, 3, 4)))
    logging.error(on_str(partial(expensive_format, 5, 6)))
```