# Python in Spark Scala via rdd.pipe redirect log

Tags: python, apache-spark, pipe, rdd

I am not using PySpark .
I am using scala to run my spark application. 
I execute a python script within the spark application by calling calling RDD.pipe. 
I want to be able to log something from the python script ,and see the logged information in the executor log.
I am not using PySpark.
I am executing a Python  script within a Spark application via the API  `RDD.pipe`.

I want to somehow provide the user the ability to debug the script by  printing some messages at the level of the Python script and have those Python scripts  available at the level of the Spark  logger.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PySpark logging from the executor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806225/pyspark-logging-from-the-executor)

Comment: I do not believe this is a duplicate @user8371915