# Logging from pandas udf

Tags: apache-spark, logging, pyspark, user-defined-functions, palantir-foundry

I am trying to log from a pandas udf called within a python transform.
Because the code is being called on the executor is does not show up in the driver's logs.

I have been looking at some options on SO but so far the closest option is this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806225/pyspark-logging-from-the-executor)

Any idea on how to surface the logs in the driver logs or any other log files available under build is welcome.

```py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@pandas_udf(schema, functionType=PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def my_udf(my_pdf):
    logger.info('calling my udf')
    do_some_stuff()


results_df = my_df.groupby("Name").apply(my_udf)
```

Comment: Try creating the logger instance  logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) inside the udf and see if it works

Comment: I didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

It is not ideal (as it stops the code) but you can do

```
raise Exception(<variable_name>)
```

inside the pandas_udf and it gives you the value of the named variable.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the work done by the UDF is done by the executor not the driver, and Spark captures the logging output from the top-level driver process. If you are using a UDF within your PySpark query and need to log data, create and call a second UDF that returns the data you wish to capture and store it in a column to view once the build is finished:

```
def some_transformation(some_input):
    logger.info("log output related to the overall query")
    
    @F.udf("integer")
    def custom_function(integer_input):
        return integer_input + 5
    
    @F.udf("string")
    def custom_log(integer_input):
        return "Original integer was %d before adding 5" % integer_input
    
    df = (
        some_input
        .withColumn("new_integer", custom_function(F.col("example_integer_col"))
        .withColumn("debugging", custom_log(F.col("example_integer_col"))
    )
```

I also explain another option is you are more familiar with pandas here:
[How to debug pandas_udfs without having to use Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71086515/how-to-debug-pandas-udfs-without-having-to-use-spark)

Edit: I have a complete answer here: [In Palantir Foundry, how do I debug pyspark (or pandas) UDFs since I can't use print statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71679561/in-palantir-foundry-how-do-i-debug-pyspark-or-pandas-udfs-since-i-cant-use-p)